# Please can someone check and let me know if email body can be refine with attractive fonts and table style

Tags: powershell

I want to send the result over the email but unfortunately, The email body is not attractive and formatted. Can someone please help to create an attractive email body?

Let me describe the script, this script will copy the file from the specific source and backup the existing file to the archive location, and copy the new file to the destination as per the file naming convention. Then send an email with the result status either file copied or not.

```
$RetailSource = Join-Path -Path 'c:\uploadtool' -ChildPath 'Retail P&C Sales Intelligence'
$GroupSource  = Join-Path -Path 'c:\uploadtool' -ChildPath 'Group P&C Sales Intelligence'      
$UATSource    = Join-Path -Path 'c:\uploadtool' -ChildPath 'UAT'
####################################################################################
# group these paths into a single array variable 
####################################################################################
$Source       = $RetailSource, $GroupSource, $UATSource


$RetailDest   = 'D:\ToolUpload\Retail-EIP'    # 1st Destination Location
$GroupDest    = 'D:\ToolUpload\Group-EIP'     # 2nd Destination location
$UATDest      = 'D:\ToolUpload\UAT'           # Added 3rd destination location in this version 1.7.2V
$ArchiveData  = 'D:\Backup\backup_{0:yyyyMMddHHmm}' -f (Get-Date)
$LogFolder    = 'D:\logs'

#Logs will be generate in csv file at the below location.
$LogFile     = 'D:\logs\uploadlog_{0:yyyyMMdd}.csv'-f (Get-Date)

# make sure the output LogFolder exist
# by adding the -Force switch there is no need to use Test-Path first, because if
# the folder already exists, the cmdlet will return the DirectoryInfo of that,
# otherwise it will create a new folder. Since we don't want output, we use $null = ..
$null = New-Item -Path $LogFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

# loop through the files in the source folders and collect the outputted objects.
####################################################################################
# $Source is an ARRAY of paths
####################################################################################
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -File -Force -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing file '$($_.FullName)'"
    # create an object with (for now) 2 empty properties
    $out = $_ | Select-Object @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {(Get-Date)}},
                              @{Name = 'Source'; Expression = {$_.FullName}},
                              @{Name = 'FileSize'; Expression = {$_.Length}},
                              Destination,                                      # depends on the file name
                              @{Name = 'Archive'; Expression = {$ArchiveData}},
                              Result

     # test if the file has a correct name
     if ($_.BaseName -notmatch 'Group-EIP|Retail-EIP|UAT') {
        # file does not have the correct naming convention
        $out.Archive = $null
        $out.Result = "Error: Incorrect filename"
    }
    else {
        # depending on its name, get the correct destination folder
        $destFolder = if($_.Name -match "Retail-EIP") { $RetailDest } elseif($_.Name -match "Group-EIP")  { $GroupDest } else { $UATDest }

        # create the backup destination folder if it didn't already exist
        # the first file in column 'Source' is now responsible for creating the backup folder
        $null = New-Item -Path $destFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

        # get the full path and filename for the destination
        $existingFile = Join-Path -Path $destFolder -ChildPath $_.Name 

        # add the destination folder to the output object
        $out.Destination = $destFolder
        try {   
            # if a file with that name already exists in the destination, move it to the Archive folder
            if (Test-Path -Path $existingFile -PathType Leaf) {
                # create the Archive folder if it didn't already exist
                $null = New-Item -Path $ArchiveData -ItemType Directory -Force
                Move-Item -Path $existingFile -Destination $ArchiveData -ErrorAction Stop 
        
                # add the archived file to the output object
                $out.Archive = $existingFile
                Write-Host "File '$existingFile' has been backed-up to '$ArchiveData'"
            }
    
            # next move the file from the source folder to its destination (either $RetailDest or $GroupDest)
            $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destFolder -ErrorAction Stop 
            $out.Result = 'OK'
            Write-Host "File '$($_.FullName)' has been moved to '$destFolder'"
        }
        catch {   # ouch.. something went horribly wrong on a Move-Item action
            Write-Warning "An error occurred: $_.Exception.Message"
            $out.Result = "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
            ####################################################################
            # $LogFile will be saved later as CSV, Do not ruin the structure
            # by inserting  '| Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Force'
            ####################################################################
        }
    }
    # output the object so it gets collected in variable $result
    $out
}

# now you can save the results as structured CSV file to open in Excel
$result | Export-Csv -Path $LogFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force

# and display on the screen using Out-GridView as the data will probably be too wide for Format-Table
$result | Out-GridView -Title 'Backup results'

# and send an email with the resulting CSV file as attachment 
# or create a nice HTML table from the objects in $result and put that in the body.
$result | ConvertTo-Html -body "<H2>Please find the following QlikView upload status</H2>"| Out-File c:\serverstatus.html
$body = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\serverstatus.html")
$EmailParams = @{
    SmtpServer = 'xyz.smtp.com' 
    Port       = '25'
    Subject    = 'File Upload Status'
    To         = "xyz@xyz.com"
    From       = "no-xyz@xyz.com"
    Body       = $body
    Attachments = $LogFile
}

Send-MailMessage @EmailParams -BodyAsHTML
```

Comment: If I understand the script and your request, I think you might be able to chop this question down to the part where you're piping the `$result` to `ConvertTo-Html` It would also be helpful to trim the script to make a [MRE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave the CSS styling to you (you can play around with it online [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/) for instance), but perhaps this is nice enough:

Create a Here-String template for the HTML body, complete with style declaration and a placeholder for where the table should go:

```
$htmlTemplate = @"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>QlikView upload status</title>
    <style>
        body, table {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #000000;}
        table {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
        th {border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 3px;}
        td {border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<H2>Please find the following QlikView upload status</H2>
@@TABLE@@
</body>
</html>
"@
```

Then, use that template string like this:

```
$body = $htmlTemplate -replace '@@TABLE@@', (($result | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment) -join [Environment]::NewLine)
# if you want, you can save this to a file
$body | Set-Content -Path 'c:\serverstatus.html'

# send the email
$EmailParams = @{
    SmtpServer  = 'xyz.smtp.com' 
    Port        = '25'
    Subject     = 'File Upload Status'
    To          = "xyz@xyz.com"
    From        = "no-xyz@xyz.com"
    Body        = $body
    BodyAsHtml  = $true
    Attachments = $LogFile
}

Send-MailMessage @EmailParams
```

Comment: Hi Theo, Thank you so much for your help. I marked this question to resolved by you and you are really champ. I never faced any difficulty ever to understand my requirement to you. one more thing if you could help, I put this script in the task scheduler to trigger in every 5 min but if there is no file in the folder, still I am getting email pop up. so I would need if file copied then only send email else do not trigger email.

Comment: @essexlake Thanks. In that case, simply add a test if there are files to process or not and if not, exit the script: `$files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -File -Force -Recurse); if ($files.Count -eq 0) { exit }` after that do `$result = $files | ForEach-Object {...}`